# Create and Use Template in Umbraco CMS

Tags: .net, content-management-system, umbraco

I am new to Umbraco.

I have to create a template in umbraco cms and need to use that, I have created templates in the templates directory found in umbraco admin panel. now I need to set it template for any page I have created. how I do this ?

any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The template only defines how the page is structured. What you need to do is create a document type which defines a set of data.

Go to document types, create new, and make sure to add your newly created template as one of the allowed templates for this document type.

Then go to Content, and create a new document of the above document type - selecting the template you created, as template. (You may need to add your newly created document type to the list of allowed types (structure tab) under the document type of your root node).

Make sure to publish when you're done